# Jquery is returning prevObject in module

Tags: javascript, jquery, browserify

Im using browserify and splitting my code into modules like this [article](https://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-structure-javascript-the-module-pattern-edition/).

I have run into a problem below where `"settings.button"` is not returning the `jQuery object $('.burger')` instead it is returning  "**prevObject**" . Am I missing something here?

any help is appreciated.

```js
'use strict';

var s,
    toggleNavigation = {

        settings: {
            button: $('.burger'),
            active: 'is-active'
        },

        init: function() {
            s = this.settings;
            this.bind();
        },

        bind: function() {
            s.button.on("click", function() {
                s.button.toggleClass(s.active);
            });

        }

    }

module.exports = toggleNavigation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably at the time `$('.burger')` runs the element doesn't exist yet (not run on document load), so you don't see anything but the `prevObject` field.

The `prevObject` field is used for chaining jQuery selectors. It would hold a reference to another DOM element if you would to use something to narrow down the selection, for example: `.filter()`.

Comment: Thanks, it was running before the dom had finished loading. I think it was the setup i had for jquery with browserify.